# AUI onclick event on all anchors not triggered

Tags: javascript, onclick, liferay, alloy-ui

I am facing a problem with the AUI().all('a').click(function(a){...}. It is not always reproducible, but it occurs 80% of the time.

The main function in our logic, with the two print statements used for debugging) is the following:

```
Liferay.on('allPortletsReady', function() {
      console.log("breakpoint #1");
      AUI().all('a').on('click', function(a) {
        console.log("breakpoint #2");
        trackingCtrl.trackAnchors(a);
      });
    });
```

When using Google chrome, I was able to run the code normally. However, using IE11 and Firefox,  I could see the messages from breakpoint 1, but I could not reach the second breakpoint (and thus the events were never triggered).

Apparently, the Liferay.on('allPortletsReady', function() {...}) is working fine, but the AUI().all(X).on('click', function(Y) {...}) is not working well with IE/Firefox, as the events are not triggered.

Do you probably know the cause of the problem? Do you have any proposal?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently even the second breakpoint is reached and the event seems to be triggered. It is more probably a problem that has to do with google-analytics (our initial goal was to track all anchor-clicks in google-analytics) or a security issue.